# How to connect my Windows Azure application to SQL Server Compact Edition version 3.5.8080

Tags: .net, azure, azure-diagnostics

I am building my first Windows azure application and i am forced to use  SQL Compact Edition version 3.5.8080 for some business reasons, i want to use SQL Compact Edition on Windows Azure. 
is there any way for it ?

Another question: Is there any link for free Windows Azure without any payment or asking for Visa or master?

Please advice !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand Application and Database role when your application is running in Cloud. The application runs in Compute part and connect to database which could be located in cloud or running on-premise. There must not a "forced" situation to use a specific database connecting to web application and I am very much sure if you have your application running on Windows Azure, you can very easily migrate your SQL Compact Edition to SQL Azure to connect with, because that would be an ideal situation to run your application on Windows Azure.

About using SQL Compact Edition on Azure, that problem is that you can not run it on Windows Azure because Azure being stateless machines. So the only option you have to run it on-premise and then connect from your Windows Azure application. In this model you would have to use the connection string which is specific to your SQL compact server running locally and the network settings are open for such connection.

Overall I think you are much better of using SQL Azure with a little added cost.

Finally you can get 90 days Windows Azure Limited capacity Trial without posting your credit card info:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/